# Selenium RC and Internet Explorer 7 with rspec for HTTPS and HTTP connections

Tags: selenium, https, rspec, proxy, internet-explorer-7

We test our rails web application with rspec and use the selenium-client (gem version 1.2.18) API in our rspec tests to let selenium RC server (version 2.21.0) steer internet explorer 7 under AP to test our application.

This worked very well until we introduced HTTPS for our login and registration process. Now the user is redirected to the secure version of the login and registration form and afterwards redirected back to the unsecure HTTP site.

For our selenium tests to work with HTTPS and internet explorer 7 we are setting up the selenium driver with "*iexploreproxy" instead of "*iexplore" and use port 4444. We also installed the CyberVillans SSL Certificate as describe here http://blog.mogotest.com/2010/04/13/how-to-accept-self-signed-ssl-certificates-in-selenium/. We run selenium rc server with -trustALLSSLCertificates. This solved the self signed SSL Certificate issues (be aware that selenium RC > 2.21 does not work because of a bug which sets a wrong valid from date).

After that we received "Permission Denied" errors, when running our tests. We found out that this is because of the same origin problem described at http://wiki.openqa.org/display/SEL/Selenium+Core+FAQ under "Why do I get a Permission Denied error when accessing my website via HTTPS?". This problem can be solved by adjusting internet explorers 7 proxy settings and using localhost:4444 to route everything through the selenium RC server. It works, but the problem is that after every test run the proxy settings are reset.

My first question is: How is it possible to make those settings persistent in the internet explorer 7? I read about custom profiles for IE but I haven't found out how to set this up for rspec tests. I also read about a proxy.pac file, but googling for solution without success.

The next problem is that when running our tests we also run into "Access denied" errors by selenium. I have no idea how to solve these and why they occur. So my second question is: How do I get rid of those under the setup described.